# Convert if statements into ternary conditional operators

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Apologize if it's seems simple, I'm stack on this. I want to convert these if statements into ternary condition :

```
if a!='-' && b!='_'
action A
else
 if a=='-' action B else action C
```

I tried this and do not work for me, it only execute directly condition C

```
a!='-' && b!='_' ? Action A : (a=='-' ? Action B : Action C)
```

How to formulate that ? thanks.

Comment: Why? There's no benefit in making it harder to read and understand.

Comment: wrap Action A, Action b and Action c in function then calling the function should work like `1a!='-' && b!='_' ? ActionA() : (a=='-' ? ActionB() : ActionC())`

Comment: u need to warp `(1a!='-' && b!='_' )` else it seems to be working like `(1a!='-' ) && (b!='_' ? ActionA() : (a=='-' ? ActionB() : ActionC()))`

Comment: Although no hard-and-fast rules, ternary operators are best for assignment rather than operation.  eg `var plural = a==1 ? "" : "s"`.  Just use an `if` for application flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though with some magic letters it works. But please DON'T do it.

Nested terenary operations are harder to read and makes your Juniors cry. Don't do it.

If you still want to do

```
(a!='-' && b!='_') ? Action A : (a=='-' ? Action B : Action C)
```

Example

```js
    var a =1;
    var b=1;
    var c= 2;

    (a==1 && b==1) ? alert("AB: true") : ((c != 1) ? alert("C: true") : alert("false"))
```

Example 2 :

```js
    var a =1;
    var b=1;
    var c= 2;

    (a==1 && b==2) ? alert("AB: true") : ((c != 1) ? alert("C: true") : alert("false"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a nested ternary statement which fits your needs:

```
var action = a != '-' && b != '_' ? "A" : (a == '-' ? "B" : "C");
```

So for example when `var a = '-', b = '_'`, `action` will be `"B"`.